# How to enable scrolling in advanced accessible charts in highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using  scrollbar: {enabled: true}, but it doesn't work for  advanced accessible charts in highcharts . Please share your thoughts

Comment: Can you provide some example code on JSFiddle ?

Comment: @lamtacvu Please find the link https://jsfiddle.net/4ywtjv07/10/ . There are actually 4 series of data . I have specified min 0 and max 2 . The last data series is missing and the scrolling as well . I want the 4th data to be visible on scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scrollbar feature is available only in Highstock. You can load Highstock source code instead of Highcharts, or add stock as a module:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/stock.js"></script>
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/q9zhfbk4/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.scrollbar

Comment: Do u know how to integrate a navigator into advanced accessible charts in highcharts(for the same example you have provided). showInNavigator: true is not working

Comment: Hi @Vinay Kumar, You just need to set `navigator.enabled: true`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0ea9msw8/

Comment: I had already done that . Since my graph is inverted my y axis acts as x axis and i need scroll bar(horizontal) for y axis

Comment: You would have to create another chart, only with navigator and connect it to the main one, like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d7o5wn1a/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have another question regarding the time intervals ,I am generally trying to get data for one year say from 1st jan 2021 to Dec 2021, but the i have the data from Apr2021 to Sep 2021. The problem is in the x axis labels are displayed from Apr 2021 to sep 2021 and not jan 2021 to Dec 2021. I dont mind if it shows empty spaces in the graph , but i need all the months to be displayed . i have tried  pointStart: Date.UTC(2020, 0, 1), min: Date.UTC(2020,0,0),max: Date.UTC(2021,10,30), but nothing works. Please suggest the solution

Comment: i have used  plotOptions : {
            series  : {
                pointStart      : pointStart,
                pointInterval   : 24 * 3600 * 1000*30
            }
        }, as well. but it doesnt work

Comment: You need to set x-axis extremes (min and max properties). Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pdLx6bza/